# can one enable CoreData in ready app?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Is there a way to enable an app to use the CoreData framework if the box "use CoreData" was not checked?
I know it could be done by altering AppDelegate.swift but I am trying to find a way to do it automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the box "use CoreData" just causes Xcode to generate some boilerplate CoreData code for you (a persistentContainer property and a saveContext() method) and dump it into your AppDelegate.  It doesn't need to go in AppDelegate, however, and you can certainly write or import your own persistent container into your app (and frankly, you should).

Checking the box also creates an empty CoreData .xcdatamodeld file to get you started with adding your own entities.  Something you can just add yourself at any time.

So if by "automatically" you mean can you add couple files to your app to give you the equivalent code of checking the "use CoreData" box, then the answer is yes.

And you should hunt around for good CoreData swift boilerplate code that fits with the needs of your app.  Apple's is just to get you started, and they rudely dump it into your AppDelegate rather than isolating it into a separate singleton, just to simplify for people just getting started with it.